# Struggling to get more insight from continuity.

Tags: continuity, definition

I feel like I do understand $f(x)$'s continuity at the point $c$ : $lim_{x \to c}f(x) = f(c)$. Though general idea seems to be clear, I still have some kind of doubts whether it is sufficient. The fact that $x \to c$ does not specify **how exactly** it approaches $c$. It does not require $x$ to take all possible values $(x_0, c)$ explicitly (but theoretically you should check each and every value from given interval).

So my questions is: am I wrong somewhy? Do I misunderstand the fact that definition above is indeed sufficient? Should not $\lbrace x \to c \rbrace$ take all possible values? Or I am right and that particular definition is kind of "common agreement" on what it **requires implicitly**?..

Comment: Don't think too hard about $x\to c$ by itself. Instead, look at the definition of the entire, single symbol $\lim_{x\to c}$.

Comment: If you work with the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity, then you will see that all values of $x$ nearby $c$ are considered.

Comment: @Arthur, actually, I can't ignore it, since then continuity is nothing but a mapping from **monotony increasing/decreasing** subset $x \in \mathbb{R}$ to possibly disordered subset $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$. And having a "not quite strict" definition given in the original post, it's not obvious nor intuitive. That's why I am curious: why so?

Comment: Continuity means precisely that whichever way $x\to c$ one has $f(x)\to f(c)$. The best way to see it is to take the sequential version of continuity: for every sequence $x_n$, if $x_n\to c$ then $f(x_n)\to f(c)$.

Comment: You’re not right about monotony.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe why?

Comment: Because a sequence $x_n\to c$ is not doomed to be monotonic.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe please see the answer above and comments, seems to clarify why $x$ is monotonic.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @gimusi sure, thanks a lot for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the continuity at a point $c$ it doesn't matter how $x$ approches to $c\in dom(f)$.

The key idea of the definition is that whatever $\epsilon>0$ you choose then you can always find a $\delta>0$ such that:

$$\forall x\in dom(f) \quad |x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$$

whch is equivalent to the condition

$$\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$$

Comment: The "key idea" which you mentioned is actually implies that $x$ takes all possible values from the neighborhood interval. Otherwise $\exists x'$ such that I could find some delta which breaks the definition you gave.

Comment: yes the condition holds for all x in the neighborhood of c, including x=c

Comment: An thus $(x - \delta; x + \delta) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $(f(x - \delta); f(x + \delta)) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Moreover, both $x$ and $f(x)$ take all possible values of a corresponding interval. And since there are really easy way to order real numbers in a monotonic sequences... you could order either $\lbrace x \rbrace$ or $\lbrace f(x) \rbrace$ such that it becomes monotonic indeed.

Comment: @52heartz it's true that $\forall x_n\to c\implies f(x_n)\to f(c)$, why do you care about monotonicity?